# I trust a lawyer. - general sense or specific one?

Tags: meaning, articles, indefinite-article

**‎Example 1**

> I trust lawyers.

**Example 2**

> I trust a lawyer.

**Example 3**

> A: Do you collaborate with a lawyer?

> B: Yes. I collaborate with a lawyer.

Can Example 2 mean the same as Example 1?

Is indefinite article "a" being used in these examples correctly?

Do they refer to a lawyer in a general sense or a specific one?

Answer (score 3):

Example 2 'I trust a lawyer' *can* mean the same as example 1 'I trust lawyers' when this phrase is accompanied with more context e.g. "I trust a lawyer (over your advise!)" or to completely switch the meaning (just for fun), "I trust a lawyer (to do their job properly!)" when directed at someone during a dialogue.

So depending on the context added further or without adding *any* other words, such as in your example where example 2 ends with a period it can still have a general sense as well as a specific sense based on in which social setting it was said or what was this said against/ after. E.g. when someone made a remark in general about lawyers vs when someone directly asked you a question about whether you knew or needed a lawyer for something.